# Current Transformers

Tags: voltage, current, transformer, shunt

I have a question about current transformers being used to measure AC currents.

Say for example, we have a 50/5 amp current ratio, meaning that when there's 50 amps on the primary, there will be 5 amps on the secondary.

**1. How is this secondary current affected by different secondary load resistances?**

**2. Is the CT manufacturer providing this current ratio based on a specific load resistance?**

If I wanted to measure this 0 to 5 amp secondary current with a micro-controller or PLC, it would need to be converted to a voltage using a series shunt resistor and op amp (that's one way to it).

**3. Would this shunt resistance affect the 1 to 5 amps from the secondary providing incorrect measurements?**

Thanks

Comment: You should read the manufacturer's datasheet. A good datasheet has all the answers you are looking for.

Comment: Probably the best reading you can find in on the https://learn.openenergymonitor.org/electricity-monitoring/ct-sensors/introduction site, where all this and interfacing is explained.

Comment: A current transformer is FUNCTIONALLY identical to a common or garden everyday "Voltage transformer". If you take :just a transformer" and rearrange the standard transformer equations then you can answer your own questions. It is actuially trivially easy t follow - once you follow it. | 1:N stepup Voltage ratio between input and output. Vout = Vin x N. Iout = Iin/N. Zin: zOut = N^2. (or Rout burden is seen as Rout/N^2 in series with the input winding.) That's it.

Comment: @JackCreasey That helped a lot. Thank you

Comment: @RussellMcMahon Thanks Russell. I see now how CT's parameters can be calculated.